# How do I use AS3 to embed an SWF file and control is using .play()?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a folder "/assets/animations" filled with .swf files. I would like my AS3 script to embed all these assets so they can be later called to play or stop.

I hear a lot about the Loader class but it looks like it doesn't embed all the files at compile time but rather grab them from a url when needed.

Basically these assets are cut scenes for a flash game. I would like all of them to be present in one final .swf so its easy to play on any machine without an internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[Embed(source="scene1.swf", symbol="scene1ID")]
public var Scene1:Class;

private var scene1:MovieClip = new Scene1();
scene1.play();
```

This should help you...
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853

Comment: For the source, would it be possible to pass it a AS3 variable? `[Embed(source=temp_url + "scene1.swf", symbol="scene1ID")]` I tried but it didn't work. I'm guessing the embed is run before the code is executed or something like that. Any ideas?

Comment: @zechdc: For the record, the Embed operation happens in the compiler, but AS3 variables are processed at runtime. It's too late to change an embed at that stage.

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot dynamically use the embed metadata command.
it's actually more like an inline compiler argument than actual as3 code.
so no, you can not use variables the embed command.