# AS3 Leaving the Flash IDE. Embeding swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I am trying to leave the Flash IDE completely, but would like to build movieClips and assets in the Flash Program. I am using FlashDevelop and I am uncertain about how to properly import the files (assets) I need, then declare them, then use them.

If I could get a simple example I would be really grateful. 
e.g. import an swf file that has layers, then declare it like

```
    [Embed(source="assets.swf", symbol="Dog")]
    myObject.myDogMC = new myDogClass
```

Clearly the above does not work, but I understand it. I can't find information that is correct and that I can understand. Please help me leave the Flash IDE. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452993/how-do-i-use-as3-to-embed-an-swf-file-and-control-is-using-play

Comment: Pan have already pointed you to a tutorial. Just remember to give your library assets a linkage name and mark them as "Export for ActionScript" in the asset's properties. In your example the "Dog" asset should have a linkage name named "Dog"